# SplitChunks is referencing window even when I opt a bundle out

Tags: webpack, webpacker, webpack-splitchunks

I am trying to use SplitChunks on a Webpack 4 application, but I am seeing "window is not defined". I am trying to opt my SSR bundle out of being chunked or affected by chunking in any way, but it isn't working:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

const notServerRendering = (name) => name !== 'server-bundle';

environment.splitChunks((config) =>
  Object.assign({}, config, {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks (chunk) {
          console.log(chunk.name);
          console.log(notServerRendering(chunk.name));
          return notServerRendering(chunk.name);
        },
        minSize: 0
      }
    }
  })
);

module.exports = environment;
```

The problem is, the first line of my server bundle is:

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["server-bundle"],{
```

This is causing my SSR execution to blow up.

---

Based on https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputjsonpfunction which I just found, I think I need to somehow change the output target to `node` from `web` for my server bundle. I'm not sure how to do that yet.

Comment: Does the suggestion from this guide work? https://survivejs.com/webpack/output/server-side-rendering/#configuring-webpack. I think the key points are to specify the output libraryTarget as ‘umd’ and global as ‘this’. You should be able to merge that config into the webpacker default.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am closer or further to having it work. That resulted in `Encountered error: "ReferenceError: ReactOnRails is not defined"`, which means ExecJS isn't seeing the react_on_rails library now.

Comment: Ah, you're using react-on-rails, that's helpful. My guess is, based on their sample project, that you'll need a separate Webpack config for SSR. https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial

Comment: I'm not sure where you are that in the sample project?

Comment: Oops, I meant to say I wasn't sure where you were *seeing* that. I honestly have no idea how to achieve what you recommended, so I'd love to see it in action.

Comment: I'd start by looking here, where the example project has several Webpack configs that appear to either be shared or serve different targets: https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/tree/master/client

Comment: I will certainly do that. I'm very curious about how it uses multiple configs. Thanks!